# List driven Scrolling Marquee

Tags: jquery

I had a friend ask about this and I wasn't sure so I thought I'd test your metal.

What would be the best route for applying a scrolling marquee to a page that is list driven?  Perhaps the better question would be:  What Jquery code syntax would enable a scrolling marquee using a list?

Comment: http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) to fetch the data and emit the desired markup needed to make the marquee work.

Edit: very easy with SPServices and the givainc plugin referenced in the question comments.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function (){
   var emptyResults = "<li>There are no current announcements.</li>";
   var toShow = false;
   $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Body' /><FieldRef Name='Modified' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' /></OrderBy>" +
               "<Where><Or><Geq><FieldRef Name='Expires' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" +
               "<Today /></Value></Geq><IsNull><FieldRef Name='Expires' /></IsNull></Or></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
     var itemCount = $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='rs:data']").attr("ItemCount");
     if(itemCount > 0){
      toShow = true;
       $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
        var bodyHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Body");+ "</li>";
        $("#marquee").append(bodyHtml);
       });
      }
     else { 
        $("#marquee").append(emptyResults);
     }
     }
   });
    if (toShow == true) {
     $("#marquee").marquee();
    }
  }); 
</script>

<ul id="marquee" class="marquee" />
```

Comment: i tried using your solution on Content Editor webpart, but no luck. Nothing is coming up.
Do i need to have or configure anything else aprt from your script? Thanks for help.

Comment: Is there a way to get the items scrolled from right <-> left? Or only Top <-> Down

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would:

1. Find a [jQuery marquee plugin](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html) that you like
2. Create webpart that uses a ListView that is populated with the List Data you care about in the structure that the plugin requires.
3. Use your plugin

This method implies that you would use the standard Object Model in the code behind, but I am sure that you could replace step 2 with something that uses the Client Object Model if you prefer.

If you are looking for the exact code to do what you want SO isn't the place.

Answer (score 1):

I am not advertising it as the best solution, but you can do that with a calculated column and a script. There's a live demo here:

http://pathtosharepoint.com/Lists/TasksVisualization/AllItems.aspx

Scrolling can be achieved directly with a html marquee tag, without the need for a library like jQuery. However, you might want to check browser compatibility before using it.

This technique is explained in several articles on my blog:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/category/the-html-calculated-column/

Answer (score -1):

Found this article quite useful for scrolling text, check out

http://sharepointlogics.com/2014/07/sharepoint-scrolling-announcement-news.html

Comment: Can you provide some context for your link? Link only answers are generally frowned upon: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer